# Copy values from one table and insert it to another jsonb field

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Please help me understand, how to copy values from one table and insert it to another in jsonb field ?

`additional_info` is jsonb field in products table.

`dedication, stories, status` this fields from books table i want to copy in `additional_info` field.

I tried like that, but obvious this isn't correct

```
INSERT INTO products (order_id, name, price, type, additional_info)

SELECT order_id, name, null, 'Book', '{\"dedication\": dedication, \"stories\": stories, \"status\": status }'

FROM books;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `jsonb_build_object`. And `\` has no special meaning in SQL, there is no need for `\"` inside a SQL string literal:

```
INSERT INTO products (order_id, name, price, type, additional_info)
select order_id, 
       name, 
       null, 
       'Book', 
       jsonb_build_object('dedication', dedication, 'stories', stories, 'status', status)
from books
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
This code i insert in my ruby script, that why i need slashes =)

This works for me, but I fetch this error 
`PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR: argument 3 cannot be null`

`HINT: Object keys should be text.`

Comment: What data types are those columns?

Comment: Data types are strings.

Comment: @PaulRo: works for me: http://rextester.com/TAQKS11795 it probably has something to do with how you run that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Though I am not sure how are you using slashes "\".

```
INSERT INTO products (order_id, name, price, type, additional_info)

SELECT order_id, name, null, 'Book', json_build_object("dedication\", dedication,  "stories\", stories, "status\", status) AS additional_info

FROM books;
```